# Spanish characters in vb.net desktop application

Tags: vb.net

I'm learning Spanish and wrote an application to display a form at random intervals at random places on the screen. Spanish words are taken from random positions in a text file. When the form appears, a Spanish word is presented with a definition below it. When I click anywhere on the form it goes away to appear again later. The form appears at any interval less than ten minutes, or whatever value I enter for that.

Spanish characters with accent marks do not display correctly. A label is being used to render. What is the best way to have it display properly. I haven't done localization or other languages in a desktop application, only web. I only want to change the one label if possible. Thanks

Comment: Using the article at  http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=174 , I coded the following and there is no difference with Spanish characters. The text is being read from a text file with a byte value of 160 for á, for instance.

    Dim resources As ComponentResourceManager = New ComponentResourceManager(GetType(Form1))
    resources.ApplyResources(Label1, Label1.Name, New CultureInfo("es-ES"))

Comment: If I have a text box I'm able to use ALT plus numpad for Spanish characters, and they show up correctly. If I save textbox text to a file it has normal ascii, but with two bytes for each of the Spanish characters. So I made a substitute matrix for each possibility. For instance &he1 becomes &hc3+&ha1. Stuffing that into the text box does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer at  http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?655592-RESOLVED-Extended-ASCII-characters-in-Stream-I-O  and used the following code:

```
  Private Const ISO_8859_1 As Integer = 28591
  Dim encoding As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(ISO_8859_1)
  reader = New IO.StreamReader(file_name, encoding)
```

It was removing the high order bit when reading the file. Labels render everything in the extended ascii set without issue.

Comment: Okay. but wouldn't it be simpler to save the file as UTF-8? That's the default text stream encoding in .NET. In any case, you can never properly read a text file without knowing the encoding.

Comment: I use notepad to edit the text file because it's easy. This is my first encounter of an encoding issue.I will certainly remember in future. I started a similar thread in Microsoft forums, and this has been an issue for several people it seems. In VB6, of course, you just read a file.

Comment: No! Text files (and strings) always have an encoding. If you don't know that it is definitely the platform default or a specific encoding, you have data loss. Notepad has an encoding selection on the Save As dialog. VB6 docs: [LinesFromFile = StrConv(InputB(LOF(FileNum), FileNum), vbUnicode)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733686%28VS.60%29.aspx)